# Is there a reference for a code snippet for how to read the global state of a smart contract?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand

I'm trying to read global state of this smart contract.

[image]

How can I get a readable state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily get a readable global state

```
function getReadableGlobalState (delta: Array<GlobalStateDelta>) {
  const r = {} as ReadableGlobalStateDelta

  delta.forEach(d => {
    const key = Buffer.from(d.key, 'base64').toString('utf8')
    let value = null

    if (d.value.bytes) {
      // first see if it's a valid address
      const b = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(d.value.bytes as string, 'base64'))
      value = algosdk.encodeAddress(b)

      // then decode as string
      if (!algosdk.isValidAddress(value)) {
        value = Buffer.from(d.value.bytes as string, 'base64').toString()
      }
    } else {
      value = d.value.uint
    }

    r[key] = value
  })

  return r
}
```

you can find [more about it here](https://github.com/joe-p/pyteal-template/blob/master/tests/index.ts#L132).